# Group files that contain identical value in name

Tags: powershell

I´ve got hundreds of files in $src with naming conventions as follows:

- prefix_123456_**012016**999.txt
- prefix0_123456_**012016**999.txt
- prefix1_123456_**012016**999.txt
- prefix_123456_**022016**999.txt
- prefix0_123456_**022016**999.txt
- prefix1_123456_**022016**999.txt

etc ...

I am trying to group the files which have identical values in their names and pipe the files to an individual .zip archive for each group. So far i´ve managed to display all files where my regex pattern matches. But now i have no clue how to pinpoint only the ones where the regex value is identical.

This is where i am right now after collecting information from SO and other sources:

```
$src = "D:\05_Tools\powershell_scripts\testbin\"
$tgt = "D:\05_Tools\powershell_scripts\testbin\output"
$filter = [regex] "_(\d*)999"

$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $src | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $filter } | Copy-Item -Destination $tgt
```

(The copy cmdlet is just for testing purposes and will be replaced by compress) As a beginner, i would really appreciate if you could provide a hint towards the right direction.

Comment: What values must be identical? The full name, the first set of numbers, the last set of numbers, or some combination?

Comment: Could `| Group-Object -Property {if( $_.BaseName -match $filter) { $Matches[0]}}` instead of `| Copy-Item` help?

Comment: @Damon What i meant was that the bold numbers are identical in three files (prefix,prefix0,prefix1). So three files always share the same set of numbers.

Comment: @JosefZ It might. I'd group by `$_.BaseName -replace '.*_(\d{6})999$', '$1'`, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers my group expr. returns an array to  `$allfiles` so iterating it and playing with `$allfiles[<index>].Name` and `$allfiles[<index>].Group` could be helpful for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Powershell version 5 you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | % {
    $zip =  ($_.Name -replace '^[^_]+_\d+_(\d{6}).+$', '$1') + '.zip'
    Compress-Archive $_.FullName $zip -Update
}
```

This just uses a regex to get the part of the file name that will create the zip file name. The key thing is the `-Update` parameter, this will create the zip if it doesn't exist or add files to it if it does exist.

If you don't have Powershell version 5 then just install a command line zip utility such as 7-zip. You can then replace the `Compress-Archive` with a call to your zip utility. You will have to refer to it's documentation to do a similar update (it may be called append).

Comment: Thanks Dave! That was the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

Next script works in Powershell 4:

```
$src = 'D:\test\SO\41087896'   # my debugging value

$filter = [regex] "_(\d*)999"

$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $src -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $filter} | 
    Group-Object -Property {if( $_.BaseName -match $filter) { $Matches[0]}}
$allfiles | Format-Table -AutoSize  -Wrap

for ( $ii = 0; $ii -lt $allfiles.Count ; $ii++ ) {
    $zipname = $allfiles[$ii].Name
    write-host "group $zipname" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    ###                    ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ debugging output
    $allfiles[$ii].Group | Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders
    ###                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ debugging output
    ### debugging output shows that each $allfiles[$ii].Group
    ### is an object of type             System.IO.FileSystemInfo
    ### and could be piped to a compressing utility
}
```

**Output** (picture seems to be more illustrative)

[image: output]

**Edit**: to narrow `$zipname` string to text shown in bold (i.e. **012016** and **022016** from the question), use next assignment instead of `$zipname = $allfiles[$ii].Name`:

```
    $zipname = $allfiles[$ii].Name.Substring( 1, $allfiles[$ii].Name.Length-4)
```

Used next code snippet to create debugging environment:

```
$src = 'D:\test\SO\41087896'
'prefix_123456_012016999.txt',
'prefix0_123456_012016999.txt',
'prefix1_123456_012016999.txt',
'prefix_123456_022016999.txt',
'prefix0_123456_022016999.txt',
'prefix1_123456_022016999.txt' | 
     ForEach-Object { 
        New-Item -Path (
                        Join-Path -ChildPath $_ -Path $src
                       ) -ItemType File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Out-Null
     }
### create debugging environment - end
```